# Affect elements NOT in div

Tags: html, css

I can not get this to work, I would like the following style to only affect `<ul>` elements that are NOT inside the `div#canvas` element. I thought that this would work, but it doesn't.

```
:not(div#canvas) ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

So, for example the first list should NOT have bullets, while the second and third one (the ones within the div) should have bullets.

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<div id="canvas">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*parent*/body > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

this will effect immediate children (all the uls that arent nested in other divs)

http://jsfiddle.net/t3Xyc/1/

OR

you could just apply a custom rule the the specific ul element you are trying to style

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

div#canvas ul {
 /*Custom style Here*/
}
```

Comment: But they can be nested in other divs just not `#canvas`

Comment: why dont you just custom style the canvas ul then? ul#canvas { list-style: disc;... }  seems a lot easier then trying to style everything else except canvas

Comment: Well then that would be too easy :) I never thought of that for some reason, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following selector should have worked if the :not() selector supported all possible selectors as its argument:

```
:not(canvas ul){
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, as per the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), the argument passed to the :not() selector may only be a simple selector, which is then specified [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn). Therefore, what you are trying to accomplish is impossible using a single css selector. The following is a little more verbose, but it would work:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#canvas ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin: 16px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
div:not(canvas) ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's matching `ul` with no parent `div`. Not the correct selector. `div:not(canvas)` is always true.

Comment: Not it is not always true, but I agree this is indeed not answering the question as you need to have a parent div for it to work... looking for a more suitable solution and will edit afterwards

Comment: It is always a match, ALL `div` tags are NOT `canvas` tags.

Comment: Indeed you are right... I was misguided by the bad design of my test case.